# Conflicting Dependencies while Installing ADT plugin for Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, eclipse-plugin, adt

I was about to start making an android app, for which I followed the startup installation guide While installing the ADT plugin it gave me the following dependency error. Can anyone please throw a light how should I finish up my DDMS-Android Installation.

..........................Error details.........................................

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android DDMS 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (epp.package.jee 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.0.20100617-0521]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.0.20100617-0521 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.0.20100617-0521)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100602-9gF78GpqFt6trOGhL60z0oEx3fz-JKNwxPY)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.0.v20100519-9OArFKvFtsd7WLUKh-DcYTS)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.0.I20100603-1100]

................................................Error report..............................................
```

**Update:-**

```
Note: 1) I finished installing Eclipse Helios v- 3.6.2
      2) Android SDK.
      3) and was On a verge of installing the ADT in Eclipse for Windows 7 from this site-> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message of Eclipse p2 is not user friendly. Generally it's caused by ADT 20 required Eclipse 3.6.2, however your Eclipse package(IDE for J2EE developers) depends on Eclipse 3.6.0. So ADT can't be installed due to dependency conflicts.

The possible solutions could be,

1. Update your Eclipse package to latest that will include Eclipse 3.6.2 or higher
2. Download a refresh Eclipse package, such as Juno or Indigo, then install ADT 20 on it

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your eclipse or download the latest eclipse version and then it must work.